# Trouble sending email in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

Having some trouble sending email from my application..

I get the following Exception

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Failure sending mail.
```

**The exception pops up when running: smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);**

**Function that should send mail:**

```
public static void SendEmail(string toAddress, string subject, string body, bool isBodyHtml = true)
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.To.Add(toAddress);
    mailMessage.Subject = subject;
    mailMessage.Body = body;
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;

    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient { EnableSsl = false };
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

**WebConfig configuration**

```
 <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <!-- Method#1: Send emails over the network -->
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="myusername@gmail.com">
        <network host="gmail.com" userName="myusername"  password="mypw"  port="465" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: gmail doesn't have an smtp server on port 25

Comment: Changed it to port 465 but I still get the same exception.

Comment: enableSsl =true needs to be enabled as well and/or try port 587 (tls)

Comment: The server that runs this code is allowed to open ports to 465/587?

Comment: I am running this locally..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how im sending gmail:

```
    static void SendMail(string sSubject, string sBody)
    {
        const string senderID = "ImTheSender@gmail.com"; // use sender's email id here..
        const string toAddress = "ImTheRecip@gmail.com";
        const string senderPassword = "passwords are fun"; // sender password here...
        try
        {
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com", // smtp server address here...
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderID, senderPassword),
                Timeout = 30000,
            };
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(senderID, toAddress, sSubject, sBody);
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            LogThis("Error sending mail:" + ex.Message);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
    }
```